# User expectation for deleting an entry in listview Android?

Tags: user-behavior, android, lists, user-research, user-expectation

My requirement for an Android app is to show an alert dialog when a user deletes an entry from the listview.

Is it really necessary to show a dialog for deleting a single entry or is it enough to show a dialog only for deleting all entry in a list?

Can anyone help with the user expectation on this issue?

Comment: Is the deletion permanent? How important is the integrity of the data in comparison to the users action? Does the deletion affect other data sources? What is the impact on the user and the data on the device?

Comment: @DarrylGodden
S the deletion permanent.
No the deletion wont affect other data sources.
For eg: The user is deleting the pages history which he visited in the app.

Comment: I'm voting to put this question on hold as opinion based because as currently phrased the answer will be "it depends..." It depends primarily on how difficult it is for the user to re-create the deleted entries.  It also depends on how likely the user is to want to re-create the entries, how likely the user is to delete items accidentally, how important it is for deletion to be quick, how frequent deletion is, and (as Darryl suggests) whether deletion may have other consequences elsewhere in the system.  Examining the importance of these things will probably resolve your question on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is related to "deleting" a record, I would say do not keep the option upfront. Until the user "hard presses" the record to be deleted. 
The trash icon appears upon hard press and there you go.

[image]

**Hard press to bring the Trash Icon**
[image]

**And the confirmation appears in line , Sure or No, cancel.**
[image]

Comment: Superb interaction but my doubt is, this is similar to iOS style, will it suits to Android Users.

Comment: @Saran why not?besides hard press is quite a prevalent interaction on Android too. You may consider doing user testing with this interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this, I'm not a fan of modal boxes or interrupting the users interaction with the current screen.

[image: UI Suggestion]

Comment: Superb interaction but my doubt is, this is similar to iOS style, will it suits to Android Users.